# Connecting to MongoDB using Azure services

Tags: mongodb, azure-web-app-service, azure-configuration

Can I make an MongoDB instance running on my OnPremise server interact with azure hosted service. 
I have seen this 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-store-data-mongodb-vm/

But the above one and most of the links suggests to create an MongoDB instance running on a AzureVM. Is it really required or can I make my way through this with an on premise MongoDB instance.

Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

@JAGBIRSINGH, you can make an on-premise MongoDB instance interact with your Azure App Services via create a hybrid connection between cloud and local, please see the article [Access on-premises resources using hybrid connections in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-hybrid-connection-get-started/) to know how to do.

Meanwhile, there is the other solution that is using [MongoDB](https://ms.portal.azure.com/?feature.relex=*%2CHubsExtension&flight=1&resourceMenuPerf=true&feature.pov2=true#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Marketplace/GalleryFeaturedMenuItemBlade/selectedMenuItemId/home/searchQuery/MongoDB/resetMenuId/) from Azure Marketplace, such as MongoDB or MongoLab which come from different publishers.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Hybrid Connection Manager works well only with SQL, even with SSAS it has some known issues. Recently I just give it a highly optimistic try for Mongo and it fails

Answer (score 0):

For now I make it work using an On Premise service interacting with MongoDb and Azure service interacting with this on premise service. This certainly add one extra hop for me but that's the only I could make it work.

If some one got some better ideas than this, please share and let us know.

Thanks